# Get-CsPhoneNumberAssignment Azure Automation Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: azure, automation, identity

Has anyone gotten the cmdlet Get-CsPhoneNumberAssignment to work in Azure Automation with a system managed identity? According to MS, almost all cmdlet are now supported for application based authentication. But I keep getting a 401 unauthorized error. I've assigend the Teams Administrator role to the identity and it has all the graph permissions (where it should only need Organization.Read.All). But still no joy...

Assigned All Graph API permissions, skype for business admin role, global reader role. Non *-cs cmdlet work, but *-cs don't. Even though according to MS they should:
[MSLearn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/teams-powershell-application-authentication?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5004983#setup-application-based-authentication)

MicrosoftTeams module in AzureAutomation is 5.6.0